# Updating Realm object from within block

Tags: ios, objective-c, realm

I have an app where a user can take a picture, save it and upload it to a database. The call looks something like this:

```
- (void)saveImage {
    // Create object
    Image *img = [[Image alloc] init];
    img.data = self.imageData;

    // Get the default Realm
    RLMRealm *realm = [RLMRealm defaultRealm];

    // Add to Realm with transaction
    [realm beginWriteTransaction];
    [realm addObject:img];
    [realm commitWriteTransaction];

    [self.client uploadImages:@[self.jpeg] completion:^(NSDictionary *response, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
        } else {
            [realm beginWriteTransaction];
            img.uploaded = @YES;
            [realm commitWriteTransaction];
        }
    }];
}
```

If I have an array of `Image` objects, `RLMResults<Image *> *imgs = [Image allObjects];` in another viewcontroller, will the image be updated automatically by Realm when this block returns? Or do I need to do another query to update it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> in another viewcontroller, will the image be updated automatically by Realm when this block returns?

Yes, the Realm objects are updated automatically if transactions are committed within other threads.

Documentation is here: https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/#auto-updating-objects

It may be delayed because the changes will be reflected every run loop. The best practice for tracking the changes, you should subscribe to [Realm notifications](https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/#notifications) to know when Realm data in an object is updated, indicating when your app’s UI should be refreshed.